# How to upload multiple images from two different file uploads fields in single form in laravel?

Tags: laravel

How can I pass multiple images files from two separate file upload option in my form and then store into database? Here are my schema and controller codes.

```
Schema::create('images', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('image_id');
        $table->increments('book_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('coverPageImage');
        $table->string('previewPageImage');
        $table->timestamps();

  });
```

Form Fields: BookID, File Upload for coverPageImage, File Upload for 
previewPageImage. Both coverPageImage and previewPageImage pass multiple images.

I was able to upload images into folder and save to database for single file upload.

```
$product_images = $request->file('coverPageImage');
foreach($product_images as $product_image){
   $coverImage_name = $product_image->getClientOriginalName();
   $upload = $product_image->move('images', $coverImage_name); 
   Image::create([
     'book_id' => $book_id,
     'cover_images' => $coverImage_name
      ]);
}

$preview_pages = $request->file('previewPageImage')
foreach($preview_pages as $preview_image){
   $previewImage_name = $preview_image->getClientOriginalName();
   $upload = $preview_image->move('images', $previewImage_name); 
      Image::create([
        'book_id' => $book_id,
        'preview_images' => $previewImage_name
      ]);
    }
```

I want to use following way:

```
 Image::create([
    'book_id' => $book_id,
    'cover_images' => $coverImage_name,
    'preview_images' => $previewImage_name
 ]);
```

But I am stuck while using foreach loop for two different fileuploads. Any suggestions or hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure there will always be a 1:1 relationship between the `$coverImage_name` and the `$previewImage_name`, then you can just push them into an array, loop the array, and create your images from within.

```
$images = [];
$product_images = $request->file('coverPageImage');
foreach ($product_images as $idx => $product_image){
    $coverImage_name = $product_image->getClientOriginalName();
    $upload = $product_image->move('images', $coverImage_name);
    $images[$idx]['cover_image'] = $coverImage_name;  
} 

$preview_pages = $request->file('previewPageImage')
foreach($preview_pages as $idx => $preview_image){
    $previewImage_name = $preview_image->getClientOriginalName();
    $upload = $preview_image->move('images', $previewImage_name); 
    $images[$idx]['preview_image'] = $previewImage_name;
}

foreach($images as $idx => $arr) {
    Image::create([
        'book_id' => $book_id,
        'cover_images' => isset($arr['cover_image']) ? $arr['cover_image'] : null,
        'preview_image' => isset($arr['preview_image']) ? $arr['preview_image'] : null
    ]);
}
```